# grep, cut and remove \n from file

Tags: awk, grep, cut, tr

I'm working with an input file containing a list of user ID's on a new line. Within a bash script I run a while loop on that input file doing an ldapsearch query using grep -E to filter for my desired results. The generated output file is currently formatted as follows (/mountpoint/out_file_1.out);

```
uid=user_id1,cn=Users,ou=Department,dc=myORG    
LDAPresource=myORG_RESname1   LDAPresource=myORG_RESname2  
uid=user_id2,cn=Users,ou=Department,dc=myORG  
LDAPresource=myORG_RESname2   LDAPresource=myORG_RESname3
```

The desired output, however, should look as follows;

user_id1;myORG_RESname1
user_id1;myORG_RESname2
user_id2;myORG_RESname2
user_id2;myORG_RESname3

So far, I've tried using grep and cut to achieve the above desired output. Here the exact commands I'm running on that first results file above:

```
grep -E '(^uid=|myORG_RESname1|myORG_RESname2|myORG_RESname3)' /mountpoint/out_file_1.out | cut -d, -f1 >&5
```

which results in a second output (/mountpoint/out_file_2.out);

```
uid=user_id1  
LDAPresource=myORG_RESname1     
LDAPresource=myORG_RESname2
```

again, running another grep with cut:

```
grep -E 'LDAPresource|uid=' /mountpoint/out_file_2.out | cut -d= -f2 >&6
```

finally produces this output (/mountpoint/out_file_3.out):

```
user_id1  
myORG_RESname1  
myORG_RESname2
```

which is "almost" what I need. The last output I've generated, needs to get rid of the newline and repeat the user ID for every Resource Name found as already described for the desired output (/mountpoint/final_output.out):

```
user_id1;myORG_RESname1  
user_id1;myORG_RESname2
```

Using:

`tr '\n' ';' < input_file > output_file` doesn't give me the desired result...

Any ideas how to achieve that? Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the actual bash script I'm running for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

# assign file descriptor for input fd
exec 3< /mountpoint/userlist
# assign file descriptor for output fd unfiltered
exec 4> /mountpoint/out_file_1.out
# assign file descriptor for output fd filtered
exec 5> /mountpoint/out_file_2.out
# assign file descriptor for output fd final
exec 6> /mountpoint/out_file_3.out

while IFS= read -ru 3 LINE; do
    ldapsearch -h IPADDR -D "uid=admin,cn=Users,ou=Department,dc=myDC" -w somepwd "(uid=$LINE)" LDAPresource >&4
    grep -E '(^uid=|Resource1|Resource2|Resource3)' /mountpoint/out_file_1.out | cut -d, -f1 >&5
    grep -E 'TAMresource|uid=' /mountpoint/out_file_2.out | cut -d= -f2 >&6
    #tr '\n' ';' < input_filename > file
done
# close fd #3 inputfile
exec 3<&-
# close fd #4 & 5 outputfiles
exec 4>&-
exec 5>&-
# exit with 0 success status
exit 0
```

Comment: The example inputs and outputs are helpful, but by themselves they leave us guessing at the actual specifications for the transformation you want to perform.

Comment: Add `/mountpoint/out_file_1.out` and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/uid=[^,]*/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)
  next
}
{
  val=""
  while($0){
    match($0,/LDAPresource=[^ ]*/)
    val=(val?val OFS:"")(val1 ";" substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13))
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print val
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/uid=[^,]*/){                ##Using match function to match regex uid= till comma comes in current line.
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)  ##Creating val1 variable which has sub string of matched regex of above.
  next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=""                              ##Nullifying val variable here.
  while($0){                          ##Running loop till current line value is not null.
    match($0,/LDAPresource=[^ ]*/)    ##using match to match regex from string LDAPresource= till space comes.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")(val1 ";" substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13))  ##Creating val which has val1 ; and sub string of above matched regex.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)      ##Saving rest of line in current line.
  }
  print val                           ##Printing val here.
}' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @z0d1ac, your welcome, cheers and happy learning. I have also added detailed explanation in post too.

Answer (score 2):

The specifications for the transformation you want to perform are unclear.  It appears that you want to process lines in pairs, taking the `uid` attribute expressed on the first line of each pair and exactly two LDAPresource attributes specified on the second line of each pair, and combining those into two lines, each containing an `id;resource` pair.

In the first place, I would not be using `grep` or `cut` for this.  `sed` or `awk` would be more suitable tools.  I'm more a `sed` guy than an `awk` guy, but I'm sure a pretty simple `awk` script could do this job in one pass.  With `sed`, I would use two:

- first, from your input to your third output with something like this:

  ```
  sed 's/^[^=]*=//; s/,.*//; n; s/LDAPresource=//g; s/ \{1,\}/\n/'
  ```
- second, to combine the resulting triples of lines to achieve the output you want:

  ```
  sed 's/$/;/; h; N; x; N; H; x; s/;\n/;/g'
  ```

You can pipe those together into one command (though I would certainly recommend writing a script for that, not typing it all at the command line):

```
sed 's/^[^=]*=//; s/,.*//; n; s/LDAPresource=//g; s/ \{1,\}/\n/' /mountpoint/out_file_1.out |
  sed 's/$/;/; h; N; x; N; H; x; s/;\n/;/g'
```

**Explanation**

Each `sed` command given specifies a semicolon-delimited sequence of steps to be performed in a cycle until the input is exhausted.

Here's the first one in multiline form, with comments

```
# The next line of input is implicitly read into sed's pattern space, sans trailing newline

# Replace the leading substring up to the first '=' with nothing (that is, delete it)
s/^[^=]*=//

# Replace the substring from the first comma to the end of the line with nothing.
# This leaves just the uid value.
s/,.*//

# Print the contents of the pattern space followed by a newline (supposes that the
# -n command line option has not been given) and replace the contents of the pattern
# space with the next line of input.
n

# Replace all substrings 'LDAPresource=' in the pattern space with nothing
s/LDAPresource=//g

# Replace the first (and only) run of one or more consecutive space characters with a newline
s/ \{1,\}/\n/

# The remaining contents of the pattern space and a trailing newline are printed at this point
# (assuming no '-n' option) and the cycle repeats.
```

The second one is:

```
# The next line of input is implicitly read into sed's pattern space sans trailing newline

# Substitute a semicolon (;) for the zero-length space at the end of the line (that
# is, append a semicolon).
s/$/;/

# Copy the contents of the pattern space into the hold space.  Both spaces then contain
# the uid plus a semicolon
h

# Append a newline followed by the next line of input (sans trailing newline) to the
# pattern space
N

# Swap the contents of the pattern and hold spaces.
x

# Append a newline followed by the next line of input (sans trailing newline) to the
# pattern space
N

# Append a newline followed by the contents of the pattern space to the hold space.
# After this, the contents of the hold space have the form
# <uid>;<newline><resource1><newline><uid>;<newline><resource2>
H

# Swap the pattern and hold spaces
x

# Replace each (semicolon, newline) pair with just a semicolon.  This completes
# joining the uid and resource pairs into semicolon-(only-)delimited form,
# leaving a newline between each pair
s/;\n/;/g

# The remaining contents of the pattern space and a trailing newline are printed at this
# point (assuming no '-n' option) and the cycle repeats.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[=,[:space:]]+' -v OFS=',' 'NR%2{uid=$2; next} {print uid, $2 ORS uid, $4}' file
user_id1,myORG_RESname1
user_id1,myORG_RESname2
user_id2,myORG_RESname2
user_id2,myORG_RESname3
```